# Using member function of Class in a Vector

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

EDIT: You need to make a vector like this:

vector myVector(5);

not like this:

vector myVector[5];

Comment: What is the exact error message, and (guessing) do you compile main.cpp as well as team.cpp?

Comment: The main issue is that you're creating an array of vectors, not a single vector. You also need to call `string` by its name `std::string` in `team.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `vector<team> players[5];` `vector<team> players(5);` has to be. With this operation you'll create a vector of 5 players. In your code 5 empty vectors are created.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a lot more errors, actually. I get the following:

```
cl /nologo /EHsc /Za /W4 stackoverflow.cpp
stackoverflow.cpp
stackoverflow.cpp(5) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'
stackoverflow.cpp(5) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
stackoverflow.cpp(9) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
stackoverflow.cpp(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'
stackoverflow.cpp(10) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
stackoverflow.cpp(10) : warning C4183: 'getName': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
stackoverflow.cpp(22) : error C2511: 'void team::setName(std::string)' : overloaded member function not found in 'team'
        stackoverflow.cpp(3) : see declaration of 'team'
stackoverflow.cpp(23) : error C2065: 'name' : undeclared identifier
stackoverflow.cpp(23) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
stackoverflow.cpp(30) : error C2556: 'std::string team::getName(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int team::getName(void
        stackoverflow.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'team::getName'
stackoverflow.cpp(30) : error C2371: 'team::getName' : redefinition; different basic types
        stackoverflow.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'team::getName'
stackoverflow.cpp(31) : error C2065: 'name' : undeclared identifier
stackoverflow.cpp(42) : error C2039: 'setRuns' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(43) : error C2039: 'setName' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(45) : error C2039: 'getName' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(45) : error C2039: 'getRuns' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
```

Class names of the C++ standard library are prefixed with `std::`. That's just part of their name. It is good practice to just always use the full name. In particular, it is very bad practice to use `using namespace std;` at global scope in a header file.

So let's remove `using namespace std` and write `std::` everywhere.

team.h:

```
#include<string>

class team {

    std::string name;
    int runs;

public:
    void setName(std::string a);
    std::string getName();
    void setRuns(int b);
    int getRuns();
};
```

team.cpp:

```
#include<string>
#include "team.h"

void team::setRuns(int b) {
   runs=b;
 }

 void team::setName(std::string a) {
   name=b; 
 }

 int team::getRuns() {
   return runs;
 }

 std::string team::getName() {
   return name;
 }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>
#include "team.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<team> players[5];
    players[0].setRuns(10);
    players[0].setName("Michael");

    printf("%s  %d",players[0].getName(),players[0].getRuns());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This removes most errors:

```
stackoverflow.cpp(22) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
stackoverflow.cpp(39) : error C2039: 'setRuns' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(40) : error C2039: 'setName' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(42) : error C2039: 'getName' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(42) : error C2039: 'getRuns' : is not a member of 'std::vector<team,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=team
        ]
```

The `a` in `setRuns` is certainly a typo. We'll also fix that. I'll also just remove the unnecessary `system("pause");`. Now we have code which exhibits *only* the error you asked about.

Let's take a closer look at the following line:

> ```
> std::vector<team> players[5]
> ```

I think the misunderstanding here is that `[5]` specifies the size of the `std::vector`. This is a misconception. A `std::vector` has no fixed size and will start at 0 elements by default. It does not need any `[]` syntax for initialization. The `[]` syntax here denotes an *array*. An array is a fixed-size collection of elements.

So what you created here is an ***array of 5 vectors***. Apparently, that's not at all what you wanted. Just replace the `[5]` with `(5)` to get the meaning of "vector that starts with 5 elements":

```
std::vector<team> players(5);
```

Now it compiles. But it will probably **crash** at run-time, because you also use `printf` incorrectly:

> ```
> printf("%s  %d",players[0].getName(),players[0].getRuns());
> ```

`printf` is a C function which was designed long before C++ existed. `%s` means that a C-style string is expected. You *could* provide one like this:

```
printf("%s  %d",players[0].getName().c_str(),players[0].getRuns());
```

Or you just use C++ streams:

```
std::cout << players[0].getName() << " " << players[0].getRuns();
```